# With/without subtitles and translation

Tags: word-usage

Instead of saying "She watches French movies with English subtitles" I can say "She watches French movies with translation, with the translation, with subtitles, with the subtitles. Please correct me if I am wrong. But if I need to say that someone watches French movies with French subtitles, or English movies with English subtitles, how do I say that? For example, if I see that a friend of mine is watching Titanic with English subtitles the movie is not dubbed, can I say "My friend is watching Titanic without the translation, without translation, without subtitles, without the subtitles?

Comment: You would not use 'without subtitles' if there were actually subtitles. You would just say ""My friend is watching Titanic with English audio and subtitles".

Comment: I think you can assume that the subtitles are the viewer's native language, unless someone is learning a language through subtitles. I often have subtitles enabled, not for translation but when the speech is indistinct.

Answer (score 3):

It's only a *translation* if the subtitles are in a different language from the audio! (Technically converting sound into a written form is called *transcription*, you wouldn't normally hear that used for subtitles though.)

Honestly *subtitles* is the easiest one to use, it's probably the most common way people express this. Apparently in North America, people use *subtitles* for translating from one language to another, and *captions* (or *closed captions*) for transcribing the audio for people who can't hear, and that can include things like describing important sounds too. YouTube's translated subtitles are under *Closed Captioning (CC)* though...

In the UK and apparently most other places, we just call words on the screen *subtitles*. Using *translation* is technically fine and accurate, but in my experience most people wouldn't say that while watching a movie. It sounds a little technical, and I feel like it's more common to hear *subtitles*, or *English subtitles* if you want to be specific about the language. And if you're talking about someone watching French movies with French subtitles, you'll probably need to be specific, or many people will assume you mean English subs.

Also, be careful with ***the** subtitles* or ***the** translation*. Both of those either imply the movie **definitely does have** subtitles (in the same language or translated to another), or you **expect** that they do. *With subtitles* or *with **a** translation* sound much more neutral, and have a sense of "if they're available".

Comment: Watch out for paraphrasing too. English subtitles of English speech are often inexact, and some translations are only "loose" translations.

Comment: I know it's not really the place to talk about it, but I have opinions about translations! For things like movies I feel like the most important thing is to carry the ideas and the tone, so you "get it" in something like the same way a native speaker would. Technically accurate translations can feel so leaden and awkward, especially for things like creative writing, songs etc. Good translation is a real skill, and it can be hard to make it work sometimes, so I can appreciate a bit of art in it ;)